How can seekg(n) not be the same as seekg(n, ios::beg)?
I read on cppreference that:

seekg(n) is not necessarily equivalent to seekg(n, ios::beg). std::basic_ifstream, for example, requires the absolute position n to come from tellg()

Can someone explain this? I don't see how it is possible that seekg(n) is not the same as seekg(n, ios::beg).

The standard does not require that seekg(n) is seekg(n, ios::beg). So, what is your question?

@3CxEZiVlQ Don't they do the same thing? Set the input position indicator n positions from the beginning

istream.unformatted#40 no "from the beginning" is used. seekg(pos) calls rdbuf()->pubseekpos(pos, ios_base​::​in) and the behavior is a stream buffer implementation detail. If unsure, call seekg(pos, ios::beg).

One function takes a pos_type, which is a class type, the other takes an off_type, which is a number. If they were always "the same", why bother to make this difference?

Consider a serial port where the beginning of the stream is likely lost to time after the first few thousand bytes transferred. A traditional file, yes, you can go back to the beginning of the file because you have the whole file. A serial port abstracted behind a file has only what's still in a buffer. Even If you used tellg to get a point in the stream, cached it, and tried to return to that point a day later, I wouldn't count on the data you wanted still being there.
